# Snake game border collision

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i'm wondering if anyone can help me with some code.
Below i have some code for a controllable circle (representing a snake head)

what could i modify/add to the below code so that when the snake collides with the border/boundaries, it repeats from the opposite side?

i have set the game resolution to 1024 x 768

any help is greatly appreciated :)

**snake.cpp**

```
#include "snake.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>

void Snake::move()
{
    switch(direction_){
    case Direction::North:
        position_.y += 10;
        break;
    case Direction::East:
        position_.x += 10;
        break;
    case Direction::South:
        position_.y -= 10;
        break;
    case Direction::West:
        position_.x -= 10;
    }

}


void Snake::render(prg::Canvas& canvas) const
{
    canvas.drawCircle(getPosition().x, getPosition().y,20,prg::Colour::WHITE);
}

void Snake::changeDirection(Direction new_direction)
{
    direction_ = new_direction;
}
```

**play_state.cpp**

```
#include "play_state.hpp"
#include "ai_snake.hpp"
#include "player_snake.hpp"
#include <iostream>

const size_t MaxShapes {5};
const unsigned int MaxScale {5};

bool PlayState::onCreate()
{
    snakes_.push_back(new AISnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(100,100));
    snakes_.push_back(new PlayerSnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(50,50));

    double x, y;
    for(unsigned shape = 0;shape < MaxShapes;shape++)
    {
        x = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenWidth());
        y = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenHeight());

        shapes_.push_back(Square({x, y}));

    }
    return true;
}

bool PlayState::onDestroy()
{
    return true;
}

void PlayState::onEntry()
{
    prg::application.addKeyListener(*this);
    game_timer_.start();
}

void PlayState::onExit()
{
    prg::application.removeKeyListener(*this);
    game_timer_.stop();
}

void PlayState::onUpdate()
{

}

void PlayState::onRender(prg::Canvas& canvas)
{
    const std::string text = "";

    canvas.blitFast(
        background_,
        canvas.getWidth() / 2 - background_.getWidth() / 2,
        canvas.getHeight() / 2 - background_.getHeight() / 2
    );

    prg::uint text_dims[2];
    prg::Font::MASSIVE.computePrintDimensions(text_dims, text);
    prg::Font::MASSIVE.print(
      canvas,
      prg::application.getScreenWidth() / 2 - text_dims[0] / 2,
      prg::application.getScreenHeight() / 2 - text_dims[1] / 2,
      prg::Colour::RED,
      text);

    for(const auto snake : snakes_) {
    snake->render(canvas);
    }

    for(Shape shapes : shapes_) {
    shapes.render(canvas);
    }
}

bool PlayState::onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event)
{
    if(key_event.key_state == KeyEvent::KB_DOWN) {
        switch(key_event.key) {
        case KeyEvent::KB_ESC_KEY:
            prg::application.exit();
            break;

        }
    }
    return true;
}

void PlayState::onTimer(prg::Timer& timer)
{
    for(auto snake : snakes_) {
        snake->move();
    }
}
```

**play_state.hpp**

```
#if !defined PLAY_STATE_HPP
#define PLAY_STATE_HPP

#include <prg_interactive.hpp>
#include "snake.hpp"
#include "square.hpp"
#include <list>


//Example of forward declaration of Snake class
class Snake;

class PlayState final : public prg::IAppState,
                        public prg::IKeyEvent,
                        public prg::ITimerEvent {
public:
    PlayState() = default;
    bool onCreate() override;
    bool onDestroy() override;
    void onEntry() override;
    void onExit() override;
    void onUpdate() override;
    void onRender(prg::Canvas& canvas) override;

    bool onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event) override;
    void onTimer(prg::Timer& timer) override;

private:
    //Snake* snakes_[2] {nullptr,nullptr};
    std::list<Snake*> snakes_;
    prg::Timer game_timer_ {0, 1000 / 30, *this};
    const prg::Image background_ {prg::ImageFile("resources/images/border.bmp").load()};

        std::vector<Shape> shapes_;
};

#endif // PLAY_STATE_HPP
```

Comment: Well you can't have a X coordinate below zero or larger than 1024, or an Y coordinate below zero or larger than 768. Now think about where you should check for that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what you mentioned is basically what i need to implement somewhere. I'm fairly new to C++ but i would think i need some sort of switch case statement somewhere?

also, i would preferably like to have some sort of grid system (20x20 or something) to handle the snake movement. Any ideas how this could be achieved?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes for a boundary of **1024x768**:

```
if (position_.x < 0) position_.x = 1023; else if (position_.x > 1023) position_.x = 0;
if (position_.y < 0) position_.y = 767; else if (position_.y > 767) position_.y = 0;
```

Note that a width of **1024** means that **X** is between **0** and **1023**!

Judging from your code, you use blocks of 10x10. If that's the case, you should customize the code above to your needs.

**Edit:**

From the comments and my answer, I merged this to code you can follow:

```
#include "snake.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>

void Snake::move()
{
    switch(direction_){
    case Direction::North:
        position_.y += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::East:
        position_.x += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::South:
        position_.y -= 1;
        break;
    case Direction::West:
        position_.x -= 1;
    }

    if (position_.x < 0) position_.x = 63; else if (position_.x > 63) position_.x = 0;
    if (position_.y < 0) position_.y = 47; else if (position_.y > 47) position_.y = 0;
}


void Snake::render(prg::Canvas& canvas) const
{
    canvas.drawCircle(getPosition().x * 16, getPosition().y * 16,16,prg::Colour::WHITE);
}

void Snake::changeDirection(Direction new_direction)
{
    direction_ = new_direction;
}
```

This is a 64x48 grid of 16x16 pixels and results in 1024x768 resolution.

Have fun!

Comment: that works perfectly! thank you :D
i actually haven't been able to incorporate a grid system into my code for the snake to move around. Is there a simple way to draw the grid so that the snake moves block by block?

Comment: Both 1024 and 768 are dividable by 16. So use a 16x16 grid. The resultion is 64x48 then and you should play with these variables and multiply them with 16 in the rendering stage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's basically what i have been trying to achieve. Any ideas what i could add to the code below to create a grid system that is dividable by the set resolution? I will ad the .cpp and .hpp files i have created for my play state

Comment: Like I said. Use `position` inside a 64x48 grid and multiply `x` and `y` with 16 in `drawCircle`.

Comment: what you're saying makes complete sense but i have no idea how to implement it in regards to code. Thanks for helping me out though, i'll try and have another look at it and any suggestions you may have for the code i've posted would be great!

Comment: how do i code position inside a grid? and modify draw circle as you mentioned?

Comment: thanks for the edit, i've tried what you said but when i run the program, the snake still moves freely and not as if it were attached to the grid system